# Responsive positioning elements

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, css-position

I have a header containing several elements. The most important parts are a slider, a banner-overlay and 3 so called 'pijlers'. The slider and banner-overlay respond perfectly but the 'pijlers' don't. They are in the right position for when the screen width is full width but when you resize the screen to a smaller width they don't move along with it to the left so they fall of the screen.

Please don't mind the pictures used, it's just for demo purposes

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kzv8L6yn/

CSS

```
body {
    width:100%;
    max-width:1000px;
    margin: 0;
    height:auto;
}
header {
    width:100%;
    height:600px;
}
.headerslider {
    width:100%;
    height 100%;
    :
}
.site-navigation {
    width:100%;
}
#custom-login {
    float:left;
    margin-left:25px;
}
.main-navigation, .headerslider, #banner-overlay, #pijler-wrapper {
    position : absolute;
    top : 0;
    left : 0;
}
#banner-overlay {
    z-index : 10;
    width:100%;
}
#pijler-wrapper {
    z-index : 10;
    width:100%
}
.pijler {
    background-color : white;
    width : 27%;
    position : absolute;
    opacity : 0.8;
}
.pijler:hover {
    opacity : 1.0;
}
#safe {
    top : 170px;
    left : 900px;
}
#durable {
    top : 252px;
    left : 900px;
}
#innovative {
    top : 334px;
    left : 900px;
}
```

HTML

```
<div id="page" class="site">
    <header class="site-header" role="banner"> <a href="#"><img src="http://tsk.nu/en/wordpress/wp-content/themes/atahualpa373/images/header/TSK-header1_1280x150.gif" id="banner-overlay"/></a>

        <div id="pijler-wrapper"> <a href="#"><img src="http://australianbluegrass.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/03/360x80-banner.jpg" class="pijler" id="safe"/></a>
 <a href="#"><img src="http://australianbluegrass.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/03/360x80-banner.jpg" class="pijler" id="durable"/></a>
 <a href="#"><img src="http://australianbluegrass.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/03/360x80-banner.jpg" class="pijler" id="innovative"/></a>

        </div>
        <div class="headerslider">
            <img src="http://www.markbsplace.net/images/CloudsOnTheHorizon-1280-x600.jpg" id="headerslider" />
        </div>
    </header>
    <div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the `piljer` positioned absolutely, so no matter what you do they will always be the exact distance from the left (900px) of the container they are in or in fact the closest container not statically positioned.

In order for them to respond, you should either use percentage positioning or if they are supposed to hug the right hand side, position them from the right instead, depending on what type of effect you are trying to achieve. For example:

```
#durable {
    top : 252px;
    right : 50px;
}
```